# Install OSMNX errors

Tags: python, pip, conda, osmnx

I tried to install osmnx by pip but confronted this error:

```
from fiona.ogrext import Iterator, ItemsIterator, KeysIterator
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

this is while I installed fiona by this command:

```
python -m pip install Fiona-1.8.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

and also GDAL by:

```
python -m pip install GDAL-3.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

both are successfully installed.
I cannot see where the problem is.
Also according to osmnx documentation I tried to use conda by typing these commands

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority python=3 osmnx
```

in Anaconda prompt. It seems that it worked successfully. It asked to activate ox environment by typing

```
conda activate ox
```

I did this and ran my script:

```
import osmnx as ox
   G=ox.core.graph_from_bbox(49.531883 , 48.849792 , -122.485153, -123.478149, 
   network_type='bike', simplify=False, retain_all=False, 
   truncate_by_edge=False, name='unnamed', timeout=180, memory=None, 
   max_query_area_size=2500000000, clean_periphery=False, 
   infrastructure='way["highway"]', custom_filter=None)
   N=ox.simplify.simplify_graph(G, strict=False)
   ox.save_load.save_graph_shapefile(N, filename='metrobike', 
   folder="database management\\OSM\\metrobike", encoding='utf-8')
```

but the error I got is:

No module named osmnx

I have no idea what is the problem. Apparently I could not install osmnx properly, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: if you intend to run the `.py` file in the anaconda environment, either spyder or jupyter notebooks, I would recommend using the anaconda navigator environments tab to check your install status. Select all packages instead of "installed" and search for `osmnx`. does it indicate that the package was installed there?

Comment: @Hugh_Kelley yes it shows that it is installed. I eventually resolved this by installing everything in pip using the package versions that Anacoda installed.

Answer (score 3):

Step by step instructions that should work... install ana/miniconda then open a terminal window and run:

```sh
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
conda activate ox
conda list osmnx
```

Verify you see it installed. Then run `python` to launch the interpreter using the `ox` conda environment. In the interpreter, run:

```py
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')
```

And it should work. For more, see the [installation instructions](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#installation) or try the official [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/gboeing/osmnx).

Comment: I am now running to exactly the same problem, using exactly the steps above. All installs fine. import networkx as nx works, but any geo* packages fail to import ( shapely, geopandas, and of course osmnx)